# Why my asm code can not link with clock_gettime and attr_copy_fd?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, linker, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to compile a asm code disassembled from GNU coreutils.

In the asm code, I see this:

```
            extrn memchr@@GLIBC_2_0:near
            extrn clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2_0:near
            extrn attr_copy_fd@@ATTR_1_1:near
```

and I declare externs like this:

```
            extern attr_copy_fd 
        extern clock_gettime
          extern memchr
```

then asm like this:

```
   nasm -f elf final.s -o final.o
   gcc -W -o final final.o
```

And I got errors :

```
   final.o: In function `loc_804BD8D':
   final.s:(.text+0x2111): undefined reference to `attr_copy_fd'
   final.o: In function `gettime':
   final.s:(.text+0xdf06): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
```

I think **clock_gettime** is defined in GLIBC and I don't know why linker can not find it(Other functions like **memchr** can be found by the linker)

What is worse, I don't know where is **attr_copy_fd**?

When building coreuitls from source code, you should link a static library **libcoreutils.a**

I tried to static link it as:

gcc -L/home/computereasy/work/lib/coreutils/coreutils-8.15/lib -lcoreutils -W -o final final.o

But nothing changed.  and I don't think I should link **libcoreutils.a** because basically all the functions required in this binary from **libcoreutils.a** has been put into the disassemble code...

Could anyone give me some help on how to link the **clock_gettime** and **attr_copy_fd** ？

Thank you!

Comment: clock_gettime():  Link with -lrt

Comment: Hi @skwllsp I tried **gcc -lrt final.o** but it still can not find clock_gettime()....

Comment: @skwllsp OK, finally I know I should use gcc final.o -lrt instead of gcc -lrt final.o ...