# Timer using NASM/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, timer, nasm

Recently i've been writing a simple compiler in C++ that translates the code written in my custom language into nasm for linux.
Everything works fine, I've written a sliding puzzles solver in my language too, but i need to know how much time it takes.
Do anyone know how to make a timer in NASM?
Thanks!

Comment: The same way you would in C in Linux...

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6636376/5162988) *might* be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes but with that method i can get the number of seconds, i need much more precision

Comment: So add the precision requirement to the question

Comment: Do you have a method to call system-calls in general in your compiler? If so, gettimeofday or similar should be available.

Comment: Or it's modern equivalent: `clock_gettime`?

Comment: Thanks, gettimeofday works, but still I haven't understood which value tv_usec contains (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html): i always get >1 million number.
If that value in in microseconds, it's more than a second... (no sense?)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) page it seems that `clock_gettime` is the best option on Linux.

[This](http://goobbe.com/questions/3035608/nasm-random-number-generator-function) blog post has some NASM code that demonstrates how to call the function and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770827/why-my-asm-code-can-not-link-with-clock-gettime-and-attr-copy-fd) SO answer shows how to link to the function in glibc, as another option.